# Why does my view does not display all pictures?

Tags: database, git, laravel, storage

So, I and a friend are working on the same project. We both have storage/public/cover_images to store our images we upload there. The pictures I upload can not be seen by him and vice versa, in other words, they are not stored in his folder and vice versa.

We have the same link

```
<img src="/storage/public/cover_images/{{ $book->image }}" style="width:150px; height:150px; float:left; border-radius:50%; margin-right:25px;">
```

and here is a picture of the storage
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOovh.png)

How we can fix that?

Example:
[I see my books but not his](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syZTm.png)

Comment: are you using GitHub to store your images? Are you both pushing to same repo & same branch or your own forks or separate branches? If you both work on the same repo, are you executing ```git pull```after your friend does ```git push``` in the end to sync up changes (and vice-versa)?

Comment: We are using gitlab, we both work on the same repository and the same branch. I git pushed my changes and then he git pulled. Git does not store the images and I beleive this is because of gitignore file in laravel

Comment: You can check if your images are being uploaded or not via Web Interface. I'm not familiar with laravel, but if it is due to .gitignore entry, you can consider different extension that is not blocked by laravel.

Comment: I read that it is good if it stays there for security reasons. There should be another way to fix that.

Comment: I mean, don't change your .gitignore, but switch to different image file format/ext. Suppose if .gitignore has jpg, you can consider using .jpeg ext. BTW, have you verified that your image files are not uploaded to gitlab?

Comment: Yes, I have checked that. Also, it does not matter what format is the image.

Answer (score 0):

Put a new .gitignore file in the folder containing your images, with the lines:

`!*.jpg
!*.jpeg
!*.png`

This will negate the root gitignore for images *in that particular folder*, and allow you to push your local images to gitlab.

See [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore#git-ignore-patterns) link for more on gitignore patterns

Comment: There is probably some other rule in your root .gitignore that is causing `storage/app/public/public` to be ignored. You'll need to find that rule and either a) remove it from the root .gitignore or b) add a new rule negating it to a .gitignore file in `storage/app/public`

Comment: Put the contents of your root .gitignore in a pastebin and link to it here if you want me to have a closer look

Comment: *
!.gitignore
!*.jpg
!*.jpeg
!*.png

That is what is there

Comment: This looks like the gitignore you created inside your `storage/app/public/public` folder on my suggestion. I need to look at the gitignore in your project root - the folder that contains `storage` as a sub-folder